# Queue/LinkedList serialization in Java

Tags: java, serialization, linked-list, queue

I have an implementation of a queue (Queue class, which is basically a linked list) - it consists of linked list of objects of Element class (with Previous/Next references) and a header for first and last element, which is also an object of Element class. I would like to serialize the Queue. The question is - how to serialize a bidirectional linked list?

Answer (score 0):

There is a lot of ways to do that. You can implement Serializable and take care about persisting all the objects. You can save all the data and relations in some structured XML. You can go with JSON.

The only problem can be if your Queue is generic (like the one in the standard library), you are going to have hard time saving an object of unknown type.

Comment: Standard Serialization can do all that, out of the box, in one line of code. No 'take care about persisting all the objects' required, and the 'problem' described in your last paragraph doesn't exist either.

Comment: So would that work during deserialization? What class will the deserializaed object have?

Comment: Same class as it was when it was serialized, of course. The only requirement is that it implements `Serializable` itself, and that its members are serializable, and so on until closure.

Comment: Java is then more clever than I thought. But then I guess one could break the encapsulation by saving the generic type and learn its true type.

Comment: How would that 'break encapsulation'?

Comment: Suppose you are given a type parameter E. You serialize the object and in the file, you can see the type there. But I suppose you can do that with reflection as well.

Comment: You can also see the type with 'getClass()' and 'instance of'; with a debugger; with toStrmg() unless overridden; ... Would you call any of those 'breaking encapsulation'? I wouldn't, and I certainly wouldn't call viewing the contents of a binary file that either. In fact I wouldnt call T an 'encapsulation' in the first place; it is just a type parameter.

Comment: I suggest that you clearly don't know enough about Serialization to be answering questions about it.